# The object initialization process

Tags: java

Here is my class looks like.

```
public class MyFirstClass
{ 

    private FirstInterface firstInterface;



    public FirstInterface getFirstInterface() {
        return firstInterface;
    }

    public void setFirstInterface(FirstInterface firstInterface) {
        this.firstInterface = firstInterface;


    aMethod()
    {
    firstInterface.getMyFunction();
    System.out.println(firstInterface); // prints some object value here.
    {

}
```

The interface:

```
public abstract interface FirstInterface 
{
  public abstract getMyFunction();
}
```

And the implementation class:

```
public class MyImplClass  implements MyFirstClass
{
}
```

I cannot find a constructor or any other initialization here. Somebody please tell me the different ways, how `firstInterface` get initialized?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Was your interface meant to be called `FirstInterface`? Are you asking about the `firstInterface` field in `MyFirstClass`?

Comment: I don't understand your question too, can you please tell us in plain English what you really trying to do?

Comment: You seem to be missing some code in MyFirstClass (between `this.firstInterface = firstInterface;` and `aMethod()`)

Comment: Yes. I tried to print `firstInterface` which printed some object value. Where this object is assigned from?

Comment: @KonstantinNaryshkin: That was a typo. Edited the question..

Comment: @HBD Then you should make a constructor to initialize your interface...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see to initaialize any attributes of a class (reference or primitive) always we go with either constrcutor or setter methods.

in your case it could be like below

1)constrcutor

```
public class MyFirstClass
{ 

    private FirstInterface firstInterface;

//other stuff goes here
MyFirstClass(FirstInterface firstInterface)
{
this.firstInterface = firstInterface;

}

}
```

and while creating your object of MyFirstClass somewhere , you have to call like below

```
MyFirstClass m = new  MyFirstClass(new MyImplClass());
```

2)setter method

```
public class MyFirstClass
{ 

    private FirstInterface firstInterface;



    public FirstInterface getFirstInterface() {
        return firstInterface;
    }

    public void setFirstInterface(FirstInterface firstInterface) {
        this.firstInterface = firstInterface;

}
```

and  to initialize do like below

```
MyFirstClass m = new MyFirstClass();
m.setFirstInterface(new MyImplClass());
```

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain it to you step by step

- First thing, you can't make a new instance from the interface by concept.
- Second, you didn't made any constructor
- Third, `aMethod` is not a correct declaration of a method
- Fourth, class `MyImplClass` should have the implementation of all the functions in the interface `FirstInterface`

So let's see the correct code:

Here I fixed the implementation of `aMethod` and also I added a **constructor**. Also I guess what you want to do in `aMethod` is printing the result of `getMyFunction`

```
public class MyFirstClass
{ 

    private FirstInterface firstInterface;

    // Constructor
    public MyFirstClass(FirstInterface firstInterface)
    {
        this.firstInterface = firstInterface;
    }

    public FirstInterface getFirstInterface() 
    {
        return firstInterface;
    }

    public void setFirstInterface(FirstInterface firstInterface) 
    {
        this.firstInterface = firstInterface;
    }

    public void aMethod()
    {
        System.out.println(firstInterface.getMyFunction()); 
    {

}
```

The interface is just fine, but by default any method in the interface are declared `abstract` and `public` so no need to add them. Also you forgot to define the **return type** of the method, I will assume it returns `String`
I also removed `abstract` before the word `interface`

```
public interface FirstInterface 
{
    String getMyFunction();
}
```

Here I added unimplemented methods (and I am sure you saw that error with the previous code).
Also Here I replaced `implements MyFirstClass` with `implements FirstInterface`

```
public class MyImplClass implements FirstInterface
{
    public String getMyFunction()
    {
        String res = "";
        // code
        return res;
    }
}
```

And finally how to call all of that

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        FirstInterface f = new MyImplClass();
        MyFirstClass ob = new MyFirstClass(f);
        ob.aMethod();
    }
}
```

So this is a complete example with the mistakes you made and their corrections, I hope this can give you a head start.

Answer (score 0):

aMethod doesn't appear to be correct at all.  Compiler errors.

I don't think any of your other code will compile, either.

You don't need abstract on an interface.

```
public interface FirstInterface 
{
  void getMyFunction();
}
```

I don't see what MyImplClass is for.  Why is it extending MyFirstClass?

I'd wonder why one of these classes doesn't implement the interface.

```
public class MyFirstClass implements FirstInterface
{ 
    private FirstInterface firstInterface;

    public MyFirstClass(FirstInterface f) {
        if (f == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("first interface cannot be null");
        this.firstInterface = f;
    }

    public void getMyFunction() { this.firstInterface.getMyFunction(); }
}
```

Comment: Yes, he asked how to initialize the interface.  I showed him.  The exception is programming by contract: making it clear that it cannot be null.